# Is it worth visiting Phoenix MarketCity shortly before official closure?

Tags: india, shopping, mumbai

I have a chance to visit Phoenix Market City in Mumbai, but due to my schedules, I'll be able to be there at around 10:30-11:00 PM. Google says, that official closure time is 11:30 PM, so I would be around an hour or even half before that. Is it still worth going there in this situation?

My friend from Mumbai says, that I should be there at least at 8 PM, because this at this hour first shops are starting to close. On the other hand, I'll be there during Friday/Saturday night, so the beginning of the weekend.

There are over 600 shops at Phoenix Market City. Is there any chance, that I'll find at least half of them open, when I arrive an hour before closing? Or should I rather assume, that there will be just several last facilities open at that late hour during Friday night?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Closing time of Phoenix Market City in Mumbai is 00:00 not 11:30. Yes you will find plenty of shops open at 22:30. There are movie shows that end after midnight and some shops stay open for that leaving crowd too. There are a few bars that stay open well after midnight. I was at the Irish bar until 00:30 with no signs of closing down and they were taking new orders as well.

Source : I was there in December 2015.

Comment: The Irish house